# My java scanner doesn't seem to be reading my input (.txt file)

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am new to Java, and I am learning how to read input using Java on Eclipse. I am using a scanner to read a .txt input file, however, it doesn't seem to be reading the very first integer in the .txt file.
Here is the .txt file:

> 2 1 4

Here is my simplified code:

```
public class Test {
    static int var;
    static int[] arr;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String fileName = "/Users/anon/eclipse-workspace/Lab/src/input-01.txt";
        readInput(fileName);
    }
    public static void readInput(String fileName) {
        File file = new File(fileName);
        Scanner fileInput = new Scanner(file);
        //Read T
        var = fileInput.nextInt(); 
        System.out.printf("var: %d", var);
        arr = new int[var];
}
```

I tried debugging, and I realized that "int var" never even appeared in the variables table on the right -- so I am not sure if "int var" was even initialized at all.

Please let me know if there are any other information that I can provide, and thank you in advance for you help and advices.

Comment: Can you please add the content of the file you want to read?

Comment: You don't print anywhere in the code given. Why should it output to the console?

Comment: I should print output on the console but I deleted it for the simplicity sake. @GBlodgett

Comment: Please add this part to the question. (In the form of a [mcve])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the input file contents. It could be a problem.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Sample {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String fileName = "src/main/resources/input-01.txt";
        readInput(fileName);
    }

    public static void readInput(String fileName) throws Exception {
        File file = new File(fileName);
        Scanner fileInput = new Scanner(file);
        //Read T
        int var = fileInput.nextInt();
        System.out.println("var = " + var);
    }
}
```

input-01.txt file content

```
10 sampletext
```

output

```
var = 10

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Just to let everyone and future viewers know, this solved the problem. Thank you!